# Unable to run popup window in jmeter 3.2

Tags: java, jmeter

I have recording script for popup window and run the script in jmeter3.2 in windown OS.

In this scenario below error occurred

> Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected

[image]

Comment: Can you show request headers you recorded?

Answer (score 0):

There could be too many possible reasons, it is quite hard to tell what's wrong without seeing your full configuration details / network dump / application and jmeter logs, etc.

Try out one of alternative solutions, i.e.

- Using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)
- Using [BadBoy Software](http://www.badboysoftware.biz/docs/jmeter.htm)
- Using [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder (Mobile and web)](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-) (by the way, this one has automatic correlation feature)

If it helps - you can try creating a ticket via [JMeter Bugzilla](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)